# Flip a coin, then repeat an experiment n times. Show exchangeable but not independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We flip a fair coin. If it is heads then we roll a die n times, if it is tails we sample a number $n$ times from the set ${1, 2, 3, 4}$ with replacement. We denote the resulting n numbers by $X_1, \dots, X_n$. Show that these random variables are exchangeable, but not independent.

I'm stuck on how to compute the joint PMF of those R.V.

Comment: You probably don't need to compute the joint PMF to answer the question. To show that they are not independent, for instance: is $\Pr[X_1\dots=X_{n-1} \leq 4\mid X_n = 6] = \Pr[X_1\dots=X_{n-1} \leq 4] $?

Comment: Yeah I think that could work, however I still need it to show exchangeability I believe

Comment: mmmh. Let $Z$ denote the fair coin flip. Can you show the $X_i$'s are independent *given $Z$*?